# SUM of multiple columns whit Mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I have been trying to get a query to work whit a SUM of columns like (kill, death and assist for players.

I have been trying whit the follow php mysql code:

```
        <div class="row">
            <h3>ScoreBoard Game Info</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="row">

            <table class="">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Player</th>
                  <th>Kills</th>
                  <th>Death</th>
                  <th>Assist</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>

              <?php
               include 'database.php'; //DB connect

               $pdo = Database::connect();
               $sql = 'SELECT player, sum(kill) as kill, SUM(death) as death, SUM(assist) as assist FROM eventgame GROUP BY player ORDER by player';

               foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                        echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td>'. $row['player'] . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>'. $row['kill'] . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>'. $row['death'] . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>'. $row['assist'] . '</td>';
                        echo '<td width=250>';
                        echo '</td>';
                        echo '</tr>';
               }
               Database::disconnect();
              ?>
              </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div> <!-- /container -->
```

I'm not been able to get this to work, can someone pls point what I'm doing wrong? I'm trying this for some days now. If the problem is the query can someone point what do I need to change or I need another approach? I'm using mysql 5.6. AW what so i need its the TOTAL of each player.

Comment: Post also the output of "SHOW CREATE TABLE eventgame;"

Comment: What is not working? You need to give more info? Are you getting an error message? Is it not echoing the rows?

Comment: You are looping over the query - *foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row)* - but you need to do a *->fetchAll()* to get the returned rows and loop over that

Comment: PDO has an execute method. Try modifying the foreach loop?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL supports expressions. You might try:

```
Select kill + death as  total, , ,
```

Comment: I`m trying to get separated total,. like total for kills, total for deaths and total for assist by player. That will get total of everything right? I mean the total for kill+death+assist.

Comment: Add this to your field list: 

     ...... , Sum(kill) + Sum(death) as total From ....